# Java Generics: Class that takes a class that takes another class

Tags: java, generics

I have a class BatchConfigurable

```
public class BatchConfigurable<T extends BatchContext>() {}
```

I am trying to write a wrapper for it. This will be another class that takes this class or any class that extends BatchConfigurable as parameter. For the declaration, I'm trying:

```
public class WrappedBatchConfigurable<E extends BatchConfigurable <T extends BatchContext>>() {}
```

This is invalid but as should be clear from the code, I want to preserve the property that the subtype of BatchConfigurable that WrappedBatchConfigurable takes should take a type that extends BatchContext as parameter. What would the syntax for this be?

Comment: No need to use generics in the wrapper. If you have a field in the wrapper of type `BatchConfigurable` it automatically can hold types that extends `BatchConfigurable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your type parameter `T` before you use it.

```
class WrappedBatchConfigurable<T extends BatchContext, E extends BatchConfigurable<T>> {}
```